# PHP and circular dependency by $this

Tags: php, singleton, this, circular-dependency

I have some doubts about circular dependency.

I want develop a module for a PHP framework. I have a class for connect with the framework and this instance several objects. In example have A and B but have more.

I want access to objects functions and parameters from others classes, but What is the best design?

```
class Main {
    $a;
    $b;

    public function __constructor() {
        $this->a = new A($this);
        $this->b = new B($this);
    }

    public function getA() {
        return $this->a;
    }
}

class A {
    $main;

    public function __constructor(Main $main) {
        $this->main = $main;
    }

    public function functionA() {}
}

class B {
    $main;

    public function __constructor(Main $main) {
        $this->main = $main;
    }

    public function functionB() {
        $this->main->getA()->functionA();
    }
}
```

I understand that I have circular dependencies. It not grow up too much because only instance these objects one time but I want make in the right way.

Other options I have are:

- Pass only objects (A, B, C, ...) to classes who need it. Probably I will end in other circular dependencies.
- Use a singleton for Main
- Avoid instance the objects with $this and make more things in Main.

I suppose last option is the prefered but I want a simple Main class for receive requests to the module.

Is there any design pattern for my structure? Any advice?

Thanks.